# SoundCloud widget not formatted as expected according to json calls

Tags: iframe, widget, soundcloud

I'm trying to speed up a site I worked on by loading SoundCloud widgets when a link is clicked but also style the SoundCloud widget as I want it i.e. like this:

http://www.instrumentalbackgroundmusic.com/royalty-free-music/happy-go-lucky/

However, I can't get certain things like the color and the type of widget (i.e. with the waveform and avatar) to show properly.

I've had a look through the [SoundCloud documentation here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/oembed#introduction), and come up with this:

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3nj7qrpz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Load iFrame on click
    $('.scload').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formatPlayer    = '&amp;iframe=true';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;color=0080ca'; // This doesn't do anything
            formatPlayer   += '&visual=false'; // This doesn't do anything
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;auto_play=true'; // Play on load
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;buying=false';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;download=true';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_playcount=true'; // This doesn't work
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_reposts=false';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_artwork=true';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_user=false';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_comments=false';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;liking=true';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;hide_related=true';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;sharing=false';
            formatPlayer   += '&amp;maxheight=166';
        var $link           = $(this);
        var getJSONstring   = 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&amp;url=' + $link.attr('href') + formatPlayer;
        // Replace contents
        $.getJSON(getJSONstring + '&amp;callback=?', function(response) {
            $link.replaceWith(response.html);
        });
    });
});
```

Certain calls aren't working it seems. Can anyone see what the problem is? I've added which calls don't seem to work in my comments.

Thanks

Osu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to change the widget type to the style I was looking for. It was to do with `?visual=true` so i changed it to `?visual=false` via jQuery. If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know!

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3nj7qrpz/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // Load iFrame on click
            $('.scload').click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                var formatPlayer    = '&amp;iframe=true';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;color=0080ca';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;auto_play=true';            // Play once user clicks link!
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;buying=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;download=true';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_playcount=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_reposts=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_artwork=true'; 
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_user=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;show_comments=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;liking=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;hide_related=true';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;sharing=false';
                    formatPlayer   += '&amp;maxheight=166';
                var $link           = $(this);
                var getJSONstring   = 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&amp;url=' + $link.attr('href') + formatPlayer;
                // Replace contents
                $.getJSON(getJSONstring + '&amp;callback=?', function(response) {
                    var widget      = response.html;
                    var src         = $(widget).attr('src');
                    widget          = $(widget).attr('src', src.replace('?visual=true', '?visual=false')); // Update iFrame src
                    $link.replaceWith(widget);
                });

            });
        });
```